# Equivalence of two pictures of odd $K$-theory

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, oa.operator-algebras, kt.k-theory-and-homology, c-star-algebras, functoriality

One can show that two functors $K^0$ and $K_0(C(-))$ from the category of compact topological spaces to the category of abelian groups are naturally equivalent. The first one is topological $K$-theory and the second is operator $K$-theory composed with the functor of "continuos functions". I wonder whether the same is true for $K^1$. Natural idea is to reduce this case to the even case using suspension functor, however there are two difficulties:
-first of all in the category of $C^*$-algebras suspension is defined by $SA=C_0(\mathbb{R}) \otimes A$ therefore it produces nonunital algebras and I don't know whether there is equivalence of functors $K^0$ and $K_0(C(-))$ in the locally compact case.
-secondly, this suspension as defined above is not the same as the ordinary topological suspension but it corresponds rather to crossing with $\mathbb{R}$.

So to summarize, my question is

> Do we have natural equivalence of functors $K^1$ and $K_1(C(-))$ and do we have natural equivalence of $K^0$ and $K_0(C(-))$ in the locally compact case?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is basically "yes, because the definitions are rigged to make it so".  The point is that you have to be careful both with C*-algebra K-theory in the non-unital case and with topological K-theory in the non-compact case, and the standard ways of being careful in both areas are compatible.

Recall that the *reduced K-theory* of a C*-algebra (unital or not) is by definition:
$$\tilde{K}(A) = \ker(K(A^+) \to K(\mathbb{C})$$
where $A^+$ is the unitalization of $A$ (just $A \oplus \mathbb{C}$ in the unital case) and the map $K(A^+) \to K(\mathbb{C})$ is induced by $A^+ \to A^+/A \cong \mathbb{C}$.  Note that if $A = C_0(X)$ where $X$ is locally compact then $C_0(X)^+ \cong C_0(X^+)$ where $X^+$ is the one point compactification of $X$, and the map $C_0(X^+) \to \mathbb{C}$ corresponds to evaluation at the point at infinity, i.e. it is induced by the inclusion of infinity in $X^+$.

Applying all of this to the suspension of a unital C*-algebra $A$, we get:
$$K_1(A) \cong \ker(K_0(C(S^1)) \otimes A \to K_0(\mathbb{C}))$$
where the map is induced by the inclusion of the point at infinity of $\mathbb{R}$ in $S^1$.

On the other hand the K-theory of the reduced suspension of a pointed compact space $(X, x_0)$ is isomorphic to the reduced K-theory of $S_1 \times X$, i.e. 
$$K^1(X) \cong \ker(K^0(S^1 \times X) \to K^0(\{\infty, x_0\}))$$
So the two definitions of degree 1 (or perhaps it should really be degree -1) K-theory agree.

Comment: Your definition of reduced $K$-theory is not quite right. Operator algebraic K-theory is covariant in the algebra, so the unit inclusion $\mathbb{C} \to A$ would give you a group homomorphism $K_*(\mathbb{C}) \to K_*(A)$, which is not what you want. What you do instead is use the homomorphism $A^+ \to \mathbb{C}$ you have from the unitisation, which corresponds to the evaluation at the point at infinity in the compactification of a space.

Comment: You're quite right - I modified the answer accordingly.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've got some questions to your answer: first, isn't $ker(K(A^+) \to K(\mathbb{C})$ just the ordinary definition of the $K_0$ group for a general $C^*$-algebra (not _reduced_ K-theory)? See for example page 111 in Wegge Olsen book. Second I understand that $K_1(A)$ is isomorphic to $K_0(SA)=K_0(C(\mathbb{R} \otimes A)$ and therefore $K_1(A) \cong ker(K_0((SA)^+) \to K_0(\mathbb{C})$. How did you get $K_1(A) \cong ker(K_0(C(S^1) \otimes A) \to K_0(A))$?

Comment: First of all, this is sort of what I mean when I say that the definitions are rigged to make everything work out - naively there is no obstruction to defining $K(A)$ to be equivalence classes of projections for non-unital C*-algebras, but the definitions are chosen to make C*-algebra K-theory agree with reduced topological K-theory because it is reduced K-theory that has the right functorial properties, is compatible with smash products, satisfies Bott periodicity, etc.  Some authors emphasize this point of terminology, and others do not.

Comment: Second, I goofed in the right-hand sides of the kernels - they should be $K(\mathbb{C})$ and $K(\text{point})$, respectively.  I edited again.  See my remarks about unitalization and one point compactification for the rest.

Comment: @truebaran Whoops. I think you are correct. That should not be called reduced K-theory, but is just ordinary K-theory. The thing is that the way K-theory for operator algebras is defined is compatible with topological K-theory "with compact support". There also is representable K- and E-theory of operator algebras, which is different.

Comment: Another way to say it is "C*-algebra K-theory is by definition reduced K-theory; nobody really uses unreduced K-theory."

Comment: Ok, I understand this point. You are also using the fact that $(SA)^+$ being $(C_0(\mathbb{R}) \otimes A)^+$ is in fact isomorphic to $C_0(\mathbb{R})^+ \otimes A=C(S^1) \otimes A$ right? And by $K^0(\infty,x_0)$ you mean _reduced_ $K$-theory of this two point space, which is just $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yes: $(SA)^+ \cong C(S^1) \otimes A$ is perhaps the key point.  What I meant by $K^0(\infty, x_0)$ was really "K-theory of the one point set $(\infty, x_0)$ in $S^1 \times X$" since the reduced topological K-theory of a compact pointed space $(X, x_0)$ is the kernel of the map $K(X) \to K(\{x_0\})$ induced by the inclusion $\{x_0\} \to X$.  As you can see I still have trouble keeping all this stuff straight...

Comment: Forgive me being so pedantic: but $C_0(\mathbb{R}) \otimes A$ is isomorphic to $C_0(\mathbb{R},A)$-the space of $A$ valued functions on $\mathbb{R}$ vanishing in infinity. Therefore its unitization would be the space of continuous $A$ valued functions which has a limit in $\infty$ which is _scalar_. However $C_0(\mathbb{R})^+ \otimes A$ is much larger (may be identified with the space of functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $A$ which have a limit in $\infty$ and this limit may be anything in $A$).